# How do I allow JS onclick with pointer-events:none;?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` over the whole page to close a dropdown menu when the big `div`is clicked. The thing is that I need `pointer-events: none;` because if I don't use it, the whole page gets blocked by the big `div`.

JS `onclick` won't work when I have `pointer-events:none;` So, I don't really know how to solve this.

```
 function test() {
            if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'block') {
               document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
           }
           else{

           }

            }

#big_div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    pointer-events:none;
}

 <div id="big_div" onclick="test()"></div>
```

Comment: Is your big_div there for the sole purpose to close your menu? If so there is a simpler solution then cover your whole viewport with a div

Comment: I don't think you can "allow JS onclick with pointer-events:none;". Actually that's the point of that property that you can't click it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans yea its there only for closing the menu. Whats the solution?

Comment: I don't know how your dropdown is made but maybe you can try with `focusout` or attaching the `onclick` event to the body when opening the dropdown

Comment: So... you're covering the page with an element you're specifically making unclickable, and you want to be able to read click events  from it?  I think the answer might just be "don't do that"

Comment: i did <body onclick="test()">but it did not get closed with that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using a div covering your whole page, put a click listener on the document, check to see if the clicked element is the menu or a child of the menu, if not then hide the menu

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");   
    var target = e.target;
    if(target !== menu && !menu.contains(target)){
       menu.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Demo

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");   
    var target = e.target;
    var openBtn = document.querySelector("button");
  
    if(target !== menu && !menu.contains(target) && target !== openBtn){
       menu.style.display = "none";
    }
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("myMenu").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
menu {
  width:120px;
  height:300px;
  background:#88DDFF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<menu id="myMenu"><span>some item</span></menu>

<button>Open menu</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went one step further and added the event as capture (more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

`pointer-events: none` means no events will come through. Instead, you should close the menu by listening to click/mousedown events on the entire document (and remove your div that is set to `pointer-events: none`).

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // You may need a better check involving e.target because
  // you won't want to close the menu when clicking inside the menu
  // or on the button (if the menu is not open)
  if (!e.target.contains(menuNode)) {
       document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully so I got downvotes for my wrong answer.

But, according to your question, you want to cover the whole page with that `div` to block the click event but you still want to receive the click event then you can do like this actually:

1) Remove `pointer-events:none;` from that `div` and add the `cursor`:

```
#big_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    cursor: none;
}
```

2) Add the listener to your `div` like I previously mentioned and prevent the click from there:

```
document.getElementById("big_div").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // Do whatever you want to do
     if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'block') {
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
     }
});
```

Comment: OP won't be able to directly click into background elements while the menu is up, that's the main point the OP made

Comment: Oh! The question is bit confusing.